# Unable to complete Dragon Rising, last objective

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Just what it sounds like. I've successfully killed the dragon, absorbed the soul, and now I'm supposed to return to the Jarl. However, when I get there, he doesn't ask me about the battle with the dragon, so I'm just stuck there on the last objective of Dragon Rising forever.

I already tried

```
setstage mq104 90
```

and

```
setstage mq104 160
```

According to [this](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Dragon_Rising), the quest ID is mq104, the stage I am unable to complete is 90, and the last stage of the quest is 160. However, none of my console commands are working. What's the problem here and what's a possible fix?

If it helps, I'm running Skyrim Legendary Edition on my Windows 10 PC.

Comment: Have you tried shouting?

Comment: Related: [Stuck on Dragon Rising quest](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/237310/4797)

Answer (score 2):

I just reloaded an older save from back in Bleak Falls Barrow. After giving Farengar the Dragonstone and defeating the dragon again, I was able to talk to the Jarl and advance to the next quest, when he makes me Thane of Whiterun.